# access 2007 change the first letter in a field of a table

Tags: sql

I have a table called **documents** one of the fields is called **location** which shows the **file path** for the document. I need to change it from `D:\........` to `H:\....`.

How can I do this using update in `sql` as the file paths vary in length and there are lots of records

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? Have you looked at what string helper functions there are for Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string helper function to achieve the same. Something like below

```
UPDATE documents SET location = 'H:' + Mid(location, 2, Len(location) - 2)
WHERE Left(location, 1) = 'D'
```

Here, `Len()` function returns the length of the string literal

`Left()` function returns 1 character from the left of the string literal

`Mid()` function give you substring from a string (starting at any position)

See [MS Access: Functions](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/) for more information on the same.

Comment: Thank you I will try this I have been working with access more and more I am just learning sql and vba I am finding it addictive

Comment: Sure and just a pointer: don't forget to accept the answer if it's helpful.